# What does "data.table" "data.frame" class mean?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, data.table

I am running `data.frames` through an analysis that takes around 45 minutes to complete. I recently began working with a new data set with similar content and (I thought) similar structure, but found that it was taking exponentially longer to analyze and producing errors that made it evident that there were structural differences.

Looking at attributes, I found that it was `$class "data.table" "data.frame"`. Running `as.dataframe()` seems to have converted it to just `"data.frame"`, and processing time seems to be normal.

Saving the question of how I created this class in the first place (I assume something to do with a clumsy extraction of a nested `data.frame`) for another time, could someone with a bit more depth in the subject than I have please explain what `"data.table" "data.frame"` actually means?

Everything I've been able to find makes them sound mutually exclusive, and I wouldn't expect the `$class` field to return the sub-class of objects within `x`, when looking at `attributes(x)`.

Comment: read [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/intro-to-the-data-table-package/). It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's good info. I do have the data.table package installed, but I didn't use anything from it on this data set that I can see. This explains why using double bracket notation seemed to resolve most of the errors it was throwing, but I don't understand how it would have gotten the data.table class in the first place, if it only refers to this package.

Comment: @Masoud, I've been meaning to learn some of the basics of `data.table`, that's a great intro to its use. Thanks for sharing. I've been thinking of using it for some large frames where R's default (and expensive) "always copy" mechanism would be mitigated by the `:=` operator.

Comment: You may have used functions from packages that use **data.table** and hence some of that package's functions may return data.table's instead of data.frame's, even if you haven't consciously used data.table.

Comment: @user8178513, I had assumed you used `fread` to read in your data somewhere, is that not true? Perhaps some other package you are using is silently coercing to `data.table`. What other packages are in that project?

Comment: Agreed with @r2evans, some functions from other packages - I can't think of a specific example off the top of my head - silently add the `data.table` attribute to call a `data.table` function.

Comment: @r2evans, @joran, I suspect that you're right. I used `jsonlite` to read the data, and it seems likely that it uses `data.table` functionality as part of its extraction

Comment: I don't think it's `jsonlite`: https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22data.table%22&type= (additionally, the package author [lists no relevant `Imports` or `Depends`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html)).

Comment: Take a look at the reverse depends/imports on the `data.table` page:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html if you've loaded any of those packages they could be responsible

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. Think I found the culprit - I didn't notice that `unique` was part of the `data.table` package. That'll do it...

Comment: `unique` is not a function in `data.table`, it's a base R function (`base::unique`, specifically) ... keep looking ...

Comment: `setDT`, then? :) Bit of a dead giveaway