# fread function read data returning two classes

Tags: r, data.table

Consider:

```
library(data.table)
storm <- fread("my.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
class(storm)
"data.table" "data.frame"
```

When the `class` function is run on the dataset it returns two classes. Why it is doing that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659969/what-does-data-table-data-frame-class-mean
I should recommend reading any tutorial on `data.table`. `fread` has argument `data.table` where you can pass `FALSE` to return `data.frame`.

Comment: why would you expect a data.table function not to return a data.table when possible?